# Beginner Question: Func return String and Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm experimenting manipulating basic Swift data types and tried to add a (basic) layer of complexity to a simple function examples I was practising from Swifts Documentation. I was able to return as a simple array but when I tried to return an array within a String I got errors. I've read all the Swift Documentation for Arrays to try and solve this first with no luck.

Here is my code for the successful Array return:

```
 func namesList(person: String) -> [(String)] {
        let register = ["RoboCop", person, "Terminator"]
        return register.sorted()
    }
```

... and my unsuccessful code:

```
func namesList(person: String) -> [(String)] {
    let register = "The alphabetic order of names are \(["RoboCop", person, "Terminator"])"
    return register.sorted()
}
```

I think the problem is in my return parameters but couldn't find a way to Return string and array?

Many thanks

Comment: What? You are calling sorted() on a String ?

Answer (score 5):

`.sorted()` operates on Sequence, and both Array and String are Sequences. `[String].sorted` (your first example) return a `[String]`. `String.sorted` (your second example) returns a `[Character]`, since a String is made up of Characters.

Your second example is not "an array nested in a String." It's just a String. `\(...)` performs string interpolation. It doesn't nest anything.

If you want to return the String, you'll need to return String.

```
func namesList(person: String) -> String {
    let register = ["RoboCop", person, "Terminator"].sorted()
    return "The alphabetic order of names are \(register)"
}
```

As a very minor point, `[(String)]` is unusual syntax and can be confusing to experienced Swift devs. The correct way to write this is just `[String]` with no extra parentheses.

Comment: Thank you! So I was trying to add the extra String text into the 'let' when it needed to be added into the Return. Just one other clarification. You say... "[String].sorted (your first example) return a [String]"... Is that the same as saying it returns a String as an Array?

Comment: Also, why is my second example retuning a type Character? I thought my second example returns type String too (as my register Let was still a String)?

Comment: `[String]` is an array of Strings. It's just a shorthand for writing `Array<String>`. So when you sort an array of strings, the result is an array of strings. There's no such thing as "a String as an Array." A String is a sequence of Characters, so when you sort it, you get an `Array<Character>`. The shorthand (and preferred) way to write that is `[Character]`. Your second example returns `[Character]`, not `Character`. The square brackets matter.

Answer (score 1):

register variable is actually a String in the second case.
You should change the return type to just string.